# Significado de "chingaquedito"

Tags: méxico, coloquialismos

Como muchos saben, *chingar*, en cierto contexto, significa *molestar*. Por otro lado *quedito* es *quedo* (con tiento, poco a poco).

¿Qué significa *chingaquedito*?

1. Una persona que molesta de manera efectiva pero "poco a poco", con discreción. O bien
2. Una persona que trata de molestar, pero no lo logra, porque sus intentos son tan *quedos* que no causan efecto alguno.

Comment: Mi mamá me dice chingaquedito porque con mis tíos no hablo y en casa soy un desmadre.

Comment: Por poner un ejemplo de uso: cuando te marcan una tarea en el trabajo, y a cada rato te están preguntando cómo vas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En base a experiencia propia, me parece que la expresión se refiere a un combinado de los dos significados que has sugerido. *chingaquedito* es aquella persona que molesta poco a poco pero continuamente, a tal grado de que llega a molestar por la frecuencia mas no por la fuerza del hecho. 
Otra manera de expresar este término es "cuchillito de palo", del cual coloquialmente se dice que *"no corta, pero cómo chinga"*, puesto que un cuchillo de tal material no consigue cortar como lo haría un cuchillo ordinario, pero sin embargo causa molestia por la insistencia.

Comment: Y la referencia?

Answer (score 1):

chingaquedito.
I.  1.  m-f. Mx. Persona que quiere conseguir algo de alguien, con buenos modales pero insistentemente, de forma que resulta molesta.

[Asale.org](https://www.asale.org/damer/chingaquedito)